# Rails 3 - Made a new controller action and view but cant route it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, custom-routes

I'm using Rails 3

I have a controller called subscriber_controller.rb

I just added an action called "def houston" and added this to my routes file

```
 match '/houston' => 'subscriber#houston'
 get "subscriber/houston"
```

but whenever I try to go to "http://localhost:3000/houston" which was the goal i get the error

Routing Error
No route matches "/houston"

What else do I need to add to the routes file to find the correct action in the controller and have the url work as http://localhost:3000/houston ?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your server?

Comment: Yea I tried that still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does "rake routes" give you?

I tried the same thing and it worked.

Check that you saved your routes file.

Comment: Yea thanks, I installed a plugin that is apparently overwriting all the routes ...so thats the issue

Comment: What plugin is that? Just curious for future reference.